# SonarQube not suppressing line using NOSONAR in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, sonarqube

I've googled and googled, and viewed quite a few StackOverFlow pages and can't find anything.
I'm using the --NOSONAR functionality to get SonarQube to ignore a line of code in PLSQL. In the analysis it recognizes that there is NOSONAR on that line because it reports an INFO Code smell, so it's working to an extent. But it also reports the Critical Code Smell we are trying to suppress, we thought that adding NOSONAR would suppress all code smells and bugs on that line and just report the NOSONAR info code smell, any ideas?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaxUM.jpg)

SonarQube verison 5.6.1

Comment: Contact support for commercial products

Comment: Hi G. Ann, thanks for the speedy reply, I've had a look around on their website and can't find any direct contact information for 'Support for commercial products'. You wouldn't happen to know how to find it, or an email?

Comment: the person who gave you the license can also give you the correct contacts.

Comment: Thanks, I've contacted our DevOps team who have the licence details.

Comment: @BenBowden What is the plugin version you use? Did you also try to use //NOSONAR as stated on the [FAQ](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-//NOSONAR) page?